# Can't Import lp_solve in anaconda (python2)

Tags: python, anaconda, lpsolve

I installed lpsolve55 in anaconda using conda. The package wasn't available in the official repository, so I installed it from another user's. However, I can't import it into anaconda. When I try, it gives me this error:

```
    ImportError: libcolamd.so.2.7.1: cannot open shared object file: No    
    such file or directory
```

I've tried googling but came up short. Any ideas?

Comment: Try installing ```libsuitesparse-dev``` (using apt; system-wide lib, not a python-lib)

Comment: Same error. If it makes a difference, I am using python2 in anaconda.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm struggling here.

Comment: You have to check yourself how this build is beeing done and how libsuitesparse should be linked. This linking seems to be the problem. In general it's not surprising that some nonofficial build is not working for everyone out of the box. Maybe build it yourself. The question is: why using lp_solve? There are much better (and much easier to install)  free alternatives. GLPK, CBC as solvers for example. pulp and cvxpy (and some more) as formulation-languages (where pulp should bring some solver out of the box; on windows cbc is brought which is in my opinion the best of the three candidates).